# Influxdb - Difference between bind adress in [graphite] and [http] of config file

Tags: jmeter, grafana, influxdb, httpservice

I need to understand what is the difference between Graphite bind address 2003 and http service bind address 8086.

I'm implementing jmeter--influxdb --grafana for real time result.In Graphite im enabling bind address 2003 and in the jmeter backend listener im using 8086 as the port.

Im not able to use influx CLI.

Im able to post the result to influxdb.

When i do above process along with-- enable [http] and enable bind address 8086.Im able to access Influx CLI and also im able to post the results to influxdb using the port 8086.No where in jmeter im mentioning 2003 which im enabling at [graphite].

Even in grfana im using http://localhost:8086 and not 2003.

I would like to know ,what actual bind address mean ?
How these two bind address make difference ?
Though in the first case i dont enable http service i'm using 8086 as the port in jmeter backend listener.How it works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `8086` is [HTTP endpoint](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/tools/api/)
- `2023` is [Graphite endpoint](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/supported_protocols/graphite/)

Graphite is a [special protocol](https://www.aosabook.org/en/graphite.html) which provides simple way of sending and plotting data.

In JMeter you have choice of:

- [InfluxdbBackendListenerClient](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/visualizers/backend/influxdb/InfluxdbBackendListenerClient.html) which uses HTTP protocol and `8086` endpoint
- [GraphiteBackendListenerClient](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/visualizers/backend/graphite/GraphiteBackendListenerClient.html) which uses Graphite protocol and `2023` endpoint. Theoretically you can use the `GraphiteBackendListenerClient` with any [other application which uses Graphite protocol](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html), not necesesarily InfluxDB

The actual choice is up to you.

- [Instructions for the InfluxDbBackendListenerClient](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results-part-2)
- [Instructions for the GraphiteBackendListenerClient](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results)

Comment: can i not change the http bind address from 8086 to any other ?i tried using which im not able to access influx CLI